# How many ways to read the palindromic word ROTATOR in this design?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows the word $\textrm{ROTATOR}$ arranged in a
> peculiar way. How many ways can this word be read assuming the equal
> least distance from one letter to another?.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{490 ways}\\
2.&\textrm{480 ways}\\
3.&\textrm{245 ways}\\
4.&\textrm{400 ways}\\
\end{array}$

I noticed that the word is palindromic, hence it can be read back and forth, thus this means that I should account for these possibilites.

In order to keep the right track for this purpose I used an auxiliary numbers atop the letters to account for these as shown in the diagram from below.

[image: Sketch of the solution]

After doing all of that I reached the conclusion that:

$\textrm{ways}=(74+74+96)\times 2 =488$

But this doesn't appear in any of the alternatives. Did I mess up something or what? Can someone help me here? Please I require a **step by step explanation** as I feel lost if my method did worked out properly?

Comment: Are only ways allowed that go from left to right or can we return to the left ?

Comment: The most important thing to say is that the main idea of your method is completely correct. However, whereas going L-R and R-L have exactly the same number of possibilities, going to the centre and back is not the same because of the extra Ts on the RHS. Two of the  answers show this more fully.

Comment: I'm not sure why you start with weight of $2$ for each $R$ and then **also** double the result at the end (for straight-across reading) - isn't that double-counting the R-to-L reading? Although as it happens, it gets pretty close to including the "folded" solutions, due to the limited difference of the two halves of the diagram.

Comment: @Joffan I did that because I encounted a similar problem where it appeared a shorter word arranged in a triangular way. But when I accounted for the number of ways it did not matched the answer, and when I doubled it, then it matched the answer. Perhaps this approach was not correct hence I asked this question for a better explanation. I also noticed that peculiar result when I doubled the ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a slightly easier argument.
Let's just count how many ways there are to go from an R to an A. The R's on one side give this:

$$R^1 \quad R^1 \quad R^1\\
O^1 \quad O^2 \quad O^2 \quad O^1 \\
T^3 \quad T^4 \quad T^3 \\
A^3 \quad A^7 \quad A^7 \quad A^3$$

Starting at the R's on the other end gives this:

$$A^4 \quad A^7 \quad A^7 \quad A^4 \\
T^1 \quad T^3 \quad T^4 \quad T^3 \quad T^1 \\
O^1 \quad O^2 \quad O^2 \quad O^1 \\
R^1 \quad R^1 \quad R^1$$

Adding those together, there are $7$, $14$, $14$, and $7$ ways to go from any R to each of the central A's. Conversely there are the same number of ways to go from each of those A's back to any R. Combining any R-to-A path with any A-to-R path from the same A we get $7\cdot7+14\cdot14+14\cdot14+7\cdot7 = 490$.

Comment: Oh superb......!

Comment: Nice work, now do it without reusing any letters :-)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I also voice my opinion that this answer is very straightforward and elegantly explained. Thus this is the reason that I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I'm a little bit confused on **why** did you multiplied $7\times 7$ and $14\times 14$?. Then you used the word, **combine**. Then I'm getting the idea that you're using $7$ ways to get $R-A$ and $7$ ways to get from $A-R$. Thus all the choices we can take is $7\times 7$ I mean for that central $A$ the same would be for each of the other central $A$ thus you add those at the end.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thus in general if I get to the same situation in palindromic words again, should I use this logic, I mean combine those at the center and then add to solve this?. I'd appreciate you can attend this doubt.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell The important principles are the [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), applied here for each letter A to count how many ways there are to join two halves (R-A and A-R) to make a complete ROTATOR path through that letter A, and the [Rule of Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) to count all the ROTATOR paths cause each path uses exactly one of the A's.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks for those articles it made it much clearer now. Specially the principle of multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

As @Peter hinted in a comment, we have to count for paths going from left to right, right to left as well as left to central $A$ column and back to left and so on.

Notation : $^{m}T^{n}$ indicates $T$ was first reached in $n$ number of ways and later $m$ total number of ways. Read right number first, left number second always.

Left to right paths (unidirectional):
$$
R \quad R \quad R\\
O^{1} \quad O^{2} \quad O^{2} \quad O^{1} \\
T^{3} \quad T^{4} \quad T^{3} \\
A^{3} \quad A^{7} \quad A^{7} \quad A^{3} \\
T^{3} \quad T^{10} \quad T^{14} \quad T^{10} \quad T^{3} \\
O^{13} \quad O^{24} \quad O^{24} \quad O^{13} \\
R^{37} \quad R^{48} \quad R^{37}
$$

Left + Right $= 2(37+48+37)=2\cdot 122 = 244$

Left to center and back to left : (top to bottom to top)
$$
^{34}R^{0} \quad ^{48}R^{0} \quad ^{34}R^{0}\\
^{10}O^{\color{red}{1}} \quad ^{24}O^{\color{red}{2}} \quad ^{24}O^{\color{red}{2}} \quad ^{10}O^{\color{red}{1}} \\
^{10}T^{3} \quad ^{14}T^{4} \quad ^{10}T^{3} \\
A^{3} \quad\quad A^{7} \quad\quad A^{7} \quad\quad A^{3}
$$

Left to center, back to left : $34+48+34=116$

Right to center and back to right : (bottom to top to bottom)
$$
A^{4} \quad\quad A^{7} \quad\quad A^{7} \quad\quad A^{4} \\
^{4}T^{1} \quad ^{11}T^{3} \quad ^{14}T^{4} \quad ^{11}T^{3} \quad ^{4}T^{1} \\
^{15}O^{\color{red}{1}} \quad ^{25}O^{\color{red}{2}} \quad ^{25}O^{\color{red}{2}} \quad ^{15}O^{\color{red}{1}} \\
^{40}R^{0} \quad ^{50}R^{0} \quad ^{40}R^{0}
$$

Right to center, back to right : $40+50+40=130$

Total ways : $244+116+130=490$

Comment: Thanks, your answer is a nice companion to Jaap's. It helped me to realize that you can account from top to bottom and viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the top A there are $1+2+1+3=7$ routes to an R. So there are $7^2$ ways through that A.

Starting from second A down there are $(1+3+3)\times2=14$ routes to an R. So there are $14^2$ ways through that A.

So the total number of ways is $7^2+7^2+14^2+14^2=490$.

Comment: There are $7$ ways to get to an $A$ but also $3$ ways. Looking these from top to the center. Looking from the bottom to the center there are $4$ ways to get to an $A$ and $7$ ways as well. But I don't know why are you squaring $7$? Why?. I am also not understanding why do you double $7$ to get the routes for an $R$ where are you getting those $1+2+1+3$ and $1+3+3$?. Can you explain this please?. In the end you are doubling %2\times 7^2 + 2\times 14^2$ but why?. I really appreciate that you can attend these questions because I'm confused.